# Why magento serving Product- images from different paths

Tags: product-images, ce-1.9.2.2

Product images are serving from different paths in view page & in sitemap.

1) product view page : `media/catalog/product/W/i/image-name.jpg` : [link1](http://totaltoys.com/media/catalog/product/W/i/Wishkey-Combat-Gun-With-Flashing-Lights-Sound-2.jpg)

2) http://sitename.com/media/sitemap.xml : `media/product/ee7/image-name.jpg` : [link2](http://totaltoys.com/media/product/ee7/wishkey-combat-gun-with-flashing-lights-sound-d1d.jpg)

but i want product images should serve from same path in both links:

**media.phtml**

```
<?php
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $dexxtz = Mage::helper('productzoom');

    $dexxtz->getCss();
    $dexxtz->getJs();
?>

<ul id="etalage">
    <li>                
        <img class="etalage_thumb_image"
        src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getImage()); ?>" />
        <img class="etalage_source_image" title="<?php echo $_product->getImageLabel(); ?>" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image'), true); ?>" />
    </li>


    <?php 
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image) {
            if(Mage::registry('current_product')->getImage() != $_image->getFile()) { ?>                
            <li>
                <img class="etalage_thumb_image" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())); ?>" />



                <img class="etalage_source_image" title="<?php echo $_image->getLabel(); ?>" src="<?php echo $dexxtz->getImageFeatured($this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()), true); ?>" />


            </li> 
        <?php 
            }    
        }
    ?>   
</ul>
```

Comment: just for knowledge purpose can you please tell me how to include image information in sitemap. as when i tried to generate a sitemap in my store its not contain any image information but in your case it is present

Comment: can you please scroll down at the end in the sitemap url or search for any product url or name in `http://sitename.com/media/sitemap.xml ` at the top , it will display categories information. but in bottom it will display product infromation.

Comment: No their is no such information you can check this https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BweKwHQ_asV2eHBVNldkbWV3S1E

Comment: @AshishMadankar i have no idea whether it will work in localhost or not. you can try once this : `catalog > Google sitemap` .

than you can click on `Genarate` button present under "Action" column

Comment: Vanila Magento 1.x does not include images in sitemap.xml . Are you using a third party module to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's local customization or additional module to include product images in sitemap.xml.

You need to use same code in both files (product view template and sitemap generator)

Comment: sorry, my account was suspened, so i counld't able to give full bounty points....